# Windows Embedded Compact 7 - Do not automatically display on-screen keyboard

Tags: motorola, .net-cf-3.5, windows-embedded-compact

I have been building a .net application in c# for Windows CE. I had originally created it for a Motorola WT4090 which runs Windows CE 5. I have now got a Motorola WT41N0 that runs Windows Embedded Compact 7. When I run the application on the WT41N0 with Windows Embedded Compact 7 the on-screen keyboard displays automatically when a text box is selected. This did not happen on the WT4090 under Windows CE 5. I do not want the on-screen keyboard to display automatically unless I have specifically coded it to.

Does anyone know how I can stop the on-screen keyboard from automatically displaying when a text box is selected?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The on-screen keyboard will automatically display when a text box is selected based on the registry setting (dword) HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\SIP\TurnOffAutoDeploy. If this is set to 0 then the on-screen keyboard will automatically display. If it is set to 1, it will not. To fix this problem you can edit the registry setting. If you are using a Motorola device you can create a file in the \Application directory with a .reg extension which contains the following:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\SIP]
"TurnOffAutoDeploy"=dword:1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to see the on-screen keyboard to appear at all (as in the case where you have a regular keyboard), then take away the "Software Input Panel" settings from the "User Interface" settings in your OS Design.